# Manual Math.pow() losing precision using float

Tags: c, math, double, precision

I am trying to do a manual power (equivalent of `Math.pow()`) in C, so in here, it's: `41619^6`.

```
  float sum = 41619;
  float a = sum;
  int k;
  for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    sum = sum * a;
  }
  printf("%f", sum);
  // sum should be 41619 ^ 6 now
```

However, I am losing precision here. I am getting `5196966085285475633789403136`, when the answer should be `5196965646007524312007756281`.

I tried changing sum to a `double` and I am still losing precision.

How can I achieve this without using `Math.pow()` (it's too slow for the test I am trying to run), and without losing precision?

Comment: Had you considered the possibility that the *reason* `pow` is slow is that it doesn't lose precision?

Comment: With that said, there's no way to store the exact value in `float` or even `double`. The types simply don't have sufficient precision to represent it. However, `pow` does a good bit better than your loop.

Comment: log_2 5196965646007524312007756281 ≈ 92. Most integers of that magnitude can't be represented precisely by single- or double-precision floats (23 or 52 bit mantissa). Perhaps this specific number happens to be one of those that *can* be represented in general, but it's not too surprising.

Comment: @delnan: No, it's not one of them. For any odd number x in the range 2^n, 2^(n+1), x^k is odd (so the lowest bit is still needed), and the highest bit is in position n*k or higher. Unless n and k are both very small, x^k is not exactly representable.

Comment: BTW, one way to slightly improve precision and speed is to restructure the operations as `(a*a)*(a*a)*(a*a)`. This requires only 3 multiplications instead of 5.

Comment: @R.. Makes sense. Thanks. I'll have to look into the test itself then.

Comment: @Darksky If you use `double` to compute `a*a`, out of the three aforementioned multiplications, the first one is exact. If you are very keen on implementing your own accurate exponentiation, I was reading this just the other day: http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/papers/REC08_Paper_Graillat.pdf and there is more where that came from: http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/publications-en.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to do [computations on Big Integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). A Big Integer is an integer whose value is greater then `2^64`. Big Integers aren't natively supported by computer architectures because they require more bits then the registers in the CPU have. There are many ways to use Big Integers in every computer language. For `C`, you will have to use a library.

I recommend the [GNU Multiple Precision](http://gmplib.org/) (GMP) library. It is typically pre-installed with most `C` compilers, requireing only `#include <gmp.h>` and the compiler flag `-lgmp`.

Read the [GMP manual](http://gmplib.org/gmp-man-5.1.2.pdf) for the large list of supported functions.

Many, many, many collaborating minds with more explicit optimization focus then you or I possess in this application domain have made the GMP libraries as efficient as conceivably possible without loss of precision.

It should be noted that `pow()` typically uses hardware lookup tables in the coprocessor and is limited to floating point numbers. This can cause noticeable imprecision for very large numbers represented in floating point form. Big Integer libraries will use a variety of mathematics techniques to maximize the computational efficiency without loosing precision such as [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

When standard wheels fail, *don't reinvent the wheel*, just look for a different, more specialized wheel.